# How to change character to italic using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this append in my ajax :

```
$('#description').append("Comment written by"+user_description+" "+now.getHours() + ":" + minutes+">>"+description2+'\n');
```

I would like to change this paragraph **"Comment written by"** to italic

Comment: ... wrap it in `<i></i>` tags? Or a `<span>` with a class on it?

Comment: Maybe, try to google "italic html" or "italic css", to self document about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to wrap the text within a pair of `<i></i>` HTML tag!

```
$('#description').append("<i>Comment written by</i>"+user_description+" "+now.getHours() + ":" + minutes+">>"+description2+'\n');
```